# Check if the sequence converges - check if it's monotonous and bound

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$a_n = \frac{1}{5+1} + \frac{1}{5^2 + 2^5} + ... + \frac{1}{5^n + n^5}$$

Here's my solution:

1. Check if it is monotonic increasing or decreasing:

$a_{n+1} - a_n = \large\frac{1}{5^{n+1}+(n+1)^5}$

Which is always $>0$, so it means that it is **monotonically increasing** for all natural numbers.

2.Now we need to prove that it has an upper bound

$1>0$,  $2^5>0$, ... $n^5>0$

After that, we have that

$5+1>5$, $5^2 + 2^5 > 5^2$, ... $5^n + n^5 > 5^n$

Taking the inverse, we have that $\large\frac{1}{5^n + n^5} < \frac{1}{5^n}$

Inadvertently, we have that $$a_n < \frac{1}{5}+ ... + \frac{1}{5^n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{5^k} $$

If we add $1$ to both sides

$$a_n + 1 < \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{5^k} = \frac{1-\frac{1}{5^{n+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{5}} = \frac{5}{4}(1-\frac{1}{5^{n+1}})$$

The series is geometric so I used the formula to calculate its sum.

Since the limit of $\frac{1}{5^{n+1}}$ as $n$ approaches infinity is $0$, we have that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n+1) \le \frac{5}{4}$$

Which means that the sequence is upper bounded. Since the sequence is monotonically  increasing and upper bounded, it **converges**.

Is this correct?

Comment: You're using $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ to prove that the same limit exists which is circular, however you can easily modify the argument directly $a_n<a_n+1<5/4$ or $a_n<1/4$.

Comment: @kingW3 could you explain where it is exactly that I'm using that? am I wrong?

Comment: @kingW3 I edited my answer because I had two typos ($a_n +1$ instead of $a_{n+1}$, and $25>0$ instead of $2^5>0$. Could you check it out now?

Comment: The line $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n+1)\leq 5/4$, implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists which is what you're trying to show. Instead of using $\lim$ you only need to prove that $a_n$ is bounded which you did $a_n<a_n+1<5/4(1-1/5^{n+1})<5/4$

Comment: @kingW3 what I did was, in the line above ($a_n +1 <...$) I applied the limit operator to both sides where we get on the left side the limit of ($a_n +1$) and on the right side the limit of $\frac{5}{4}$ which is the same number. I thought it could work

Comment: You can only apply the limit operator when the limit(s) exists. Here the limits of both sides exist, though the existance of the limit $a_n+1$ is basically what you're trying to prove. Anyway you're only required to show that $a_n$ is bounded (you already showed increasing) no need to go any further with limits.